# Partial differential equations problem with boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to solve this problem .

any hint or help will be  appreciated  .

the problem is taken from a past exam .

$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}+2\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +8u+ 2x(1-4t)+cos(3x) , 0< x< \frac{\pi}{2} $ .

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t)=t$

$u(\frac{\pi}{2},t)=\frac{\pi t}{2}$

$u(x,0)=0$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=x$

1. i tried separation of variable + super position principle but with no point since the problem is in the boundary condition i don't know how to use .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regards @Bey . If I may, when using separation of variables, 
$$ u = X(x)T(t) $$
from the boundary and initial conditions, you would be able to get

- From $u_{x}(0,t) = t$, then we get
  $$  T(t) = \frac{t}{X'(0)}, \:\:\: T(0)=0 $$
- From $u(\frac{\pi}{2},t) = \frac{\pi}{2}t$, we get
  $$ X(\pi/2)T(t) = \frac{\pi}{2}t \implies  X'(0) = 2\frac{X(\frac{\pi}{2})}{\pi} $$
- The initial condition implies $T(0)=0$
- From $u_{t}(x,0) = t$, we get
  $$ X(x)= \frac{x}{T'(0)} $$

So 
$$  u(x,t) = X(x)T(t) = \frac{xt}{X'(0)T'(0)}=\frac{xt}{C} $$
You would also be able to see that $C=1$.
$$ u = xt $$ 
This solution is true for
$$u_{tt} + 2u_{t} = u_{xx} + 8u + 2x(1-4t) $$

---

This is a small contribution.. I also wonder how is the $\cos(3x)$ term..

If you put 
$$ u(x,t) = xt + g(t) \cos(3x)$$
then put this to the PDE, then you must find the function $g(t)$ such that
$$ g''(t) \cos(3x) + 2g'(t) \cos(3x) + 9 g(t) \cos(3x) - 8 g(t) \cos(3x) = \cos(3x) $$
which implies that you may solve  $ g''(t) + 2g'(t) + g(t) = 1 $. The PDE initial conditions imply the $g(t)$ initial conditions : 
$$g(0)=g'(0)=0$$

Hope this helps. Regards, Arief

Comment: thanks for your help ^^ .i will try Laplace transform on the equation with respect to variable x .

Comment: @BeyAlexander  . The solution $$ u(x,t) = xt + g(t) \cos(3x) $$ 
satisfy all the PDE boundary conditions. Next, you could find the function $g(t)$ by solving the ODE with the initial conditions.

Comment: g(t)=exp(-t)(-1-t)+1